# Storing element height in var via jquery

Tags: jquery

EDIT:

Here is the code exactly as it is in my file:

Relevant HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseover="return overlib('Farewell - N.C. Hunter Hayden', HEIGHT, -1, WIDTH, -1, ABOVE);" onmouseout="return nd();" onclick="andherewego(1); setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('farewell').play();},965);"><div id="note_1"></div></a>
```

Clicking this will call the function andherewego(p).  Here is that function:

```
function andherewego(p){    // p is the # of the note pressed

initiatestafffade();    // set times for notes and notation to fade,
                        // and fades them
setTimeout(function(){
    changingoftheguard(p);  // show writing_p, paper, marginline,
                            // back_p
    hackemoff(p);           // re-define height for paper, marginline,
                            // back
    hidingfromjudgement(p); // determines how many covers to show and
                            // shows
                            // them
    nowheretohide(p);       // set times for covers to fade, and fades
                            //them

}, 950);
```

}

This function calls hackemoff(p), which I have put below:

```
function hackemoff(p){
var writingheight = $("writing_"+p).height();
alert(writingheight);
$("#paper").height(writingheight-300+50);
$("#marginline").height(writingheight+50);
$("#back_"+p).height(writingheight+50);
```

}

That is the code.  If my syntax is indeed flawless, as you say, for the line

```
    var writingheight = $("writing_"+p).height();
```

then I do not understand why writingheight is null.  I am grateful for you to be looking at this.

ORIGINAL POST:

I am trying to store the value of an element's height in a variable, so I can use it to set the height of other elements.  My issue is  with storing the height.  I thought I could try this:

```
var writingheight = $("#writing_"+p).height;
```

(There are several div#writing_*x* elements.)

Why does this store a long mess in `writingheight` instead of the height value?

Comment: Here's the [truth](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: If you have a look at the **documentation** you will see that `height` is a function: http://api.jquery.com/height/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute it by `()`, or you are just assigning the jquery function to the variable.

```
var writingheight = $("#writing_"+p).height();
```

Comment: I now have that, but writingheight comes out null.  Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: @Oijl No, syntax is all right. Give your html code or an example.

Comment: @Oijl So what is the result of `$("#writing_1").height()` ?

Comment: The result is Null.  There is nothing there.

Comment: @Oijl Then it should be null. Please check the id.

Comment: Well, it was the () that I needed to learn about.  I didn't know that before.  The problem after I had added them was that I had taken off the # before the id, and had forgotten, or had falsely remembered putting it on, so I wasn't looking for it - my eyes aren't good for coding.  Anyway, this was educational.

Answer (score 0):

dont forget (), you should write height()